# Minimum supported gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have been looking around for a fix for this issue. The fix that I found is to update the gradle-wrapper.properties file with the new version. This was automatically updated to: gradle-4.4-all.zip when I recently updated my Android studio. However, I am still having the same issue is as if the project is not recognizing I have 4.4 version added. Am I missing another location where to add this? I verified on my project structure as well that gradle version is 4.4. Any ideas would be great?

Comment: check your `<project_folder>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file, it should have `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip` also check your local gradle folder : `home/.gradle/dists` - it should contain : `gradle-4.4-all`.  If both are there, try invalidating caches and restarting, or as a last resort nuke the `.gradle/dists` folder.

Comment: @MarkKeen thank you for your response! I verified all this information and unfortunately same issue. The weird thing is I have other projects in 4.4 and they are running fine with no problems

Comment: I finally got it working thank you for your help! I was running the project with gradle that was on my computer not in android studio and that was version 4.1. Always the little things that take time! Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: If you post this as an answer i will accept it!

Comment: Glad your issue is solved. I think I only led you on a path (pardon the pun) to your solution, so not really sure I should get the credit for it.  If you think it might help others think about posting your complete solution and accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error working with Flutter, make sure you are looking within the correct folder for the config.  You have 2 gradle folders in the root of your app.  I wasted so much time until I discovered this because I'm new to Flutter/Android Studio.

```
MyApp
  |-Android
      |-.gradle (Not this one)
      |-app
      |-gradle <-- THIS ONE
  |-ios
  |-lib
```